# I want to make sure people can't build on my Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have used world guard and other build protection addons but it is a Prison server so I can't put it everywhere. I am using MineHut to host my server.

Comment: Please clarify.  What is your question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we can use the `server.properties` file:

- we can change the default mode: `gamemode=adventure`
- or, even better, we can set a spawn protection:
  `spawn-protection=9999999` (one person needs to be OP for this to work)

Answer (score 0):

WorldGuard has what we call "regions". You can assign different flags and permissions for cuboids within a world. Simply select a region with WorldEdit and `rg define [name]`.

From there, you can set up the permissions and flags with `rg flag [name] [flag] [args ...]`. You can read up [here](https://worldguard.enginehub.org/en/latest/regions/) for more information.

Note: `/wg` (alias of `/worldguard`) is only for system commands (ie. Getting WorldGuard's version), and `/rg` is an alias for `/region`.

Comment: It didn't work D;

Comment: @crazygamer115 Did you try installing WorldGuard? The answer you accepted is an "everywhere" vanilla answer. It sounds like you want to use plugins but don't want to or know how to use them.